# Accessing list of child elements with web components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm trying to define some web-components like

```
<my-parent>
  <my-child></my-child>
  <my-child></my-child>
</my-parent>
```

In the definition of `my-parent` I would like to access all its children and tweak how they are actually rendered. I am currently using https://hybrids.js.org (I'm not attached to the tool, though) and I would like to do something like

```js
export default {
  inner: children((hybrids) => true),
  render: ({ inner }) => return html`
<div>
  ${inner.map((child) => child.render();)}
</div>
  `}
};
```

but `child.render()` prints `[object ShadowRoot]`.

I know about `slot`s, but it seems they do not allow to access a list of inner elements and alter their rendering.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: ``my-parent`` can only access its (light)DOM after the whole element was parsed. ``my-child`` controls how it is rendered. Do you want to prevent that?

Comment: it is fine that every `my-child` renders itself. I just want to add stuff between the various `my-child` elements

Comment: Only in FireFox can you access the element DOM in the ``connectedCallback``. Standard practice is to add a ``setTimeout`` in the callback  to wait for the Event Loop to clear and all (element) DOM is ready. So children will have rendered, and you can "add stuff" just like in regular DOM. With ``.insertAdjacentHTML`` if you need to inject content **between** elements.